# Only show My Account when logged in

Tags: customer-account

At the moment the My Account link is not being shown in my top header. I would like to have it shown when the customer is logged in. I am using the below code in customer.xml

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

I believe that the code is correct, but I guess it has previously been removed directly from a template file. In which template would it normally be defined?

Answer (score 0):

in customer.xml at your theme before it is look like

```
 <default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Remove my account link from `default` tag to `Customer_logged_in`

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

Change it with

**After change at customer.xml**

```
<default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">

        </reference>
    </default>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
-->

<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

hope this will sure help you.